# Understanding SQLite query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm training with `SQLite` and i'm trying to achieve the same result as the search result implemented in USDA.

In [USDA food list search](http://ndb.nal.usda.gov/ndb/foods) if I search for "chicken breast cooked roasted" the search results 56 results.
I'm can't figure out the pattern. Using the same database as they, If i use the following query:

```
SELECT *
  FROM FOODDATA
 WHERE FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%' OR FOODDES LIKE '%breast%' OR FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%' OR FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%';
```

It gives me more than 2000 results. For me that makes sense. Using `AND` replacing the `OR` only gives me 2 results. Once again, it makes sense.

What kind of query are USDA performing?

Comment: they might be using full text search: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search

Comment: Do you have a database containing all the data that that website has?

Comment: Some of the results seem to refer to 'turkey breast cooked roasted', so this doesn't look like a simple SQL query. They may be looking for 3 out of the 4 keywords, or they may have alternatives (ie use turkey instead of chicken)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Yes. They provide the database files for download

Comment: @sgmoore I've noticed that. That was something that lead me to thinking that there was some other pattern than a simple SQL search

Comment: @MilenPavlov Thanks. Followed your suggestion and created a table with full text support but can't replicate the behaviour. Like sgmoore said, probably using other alternatives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can investigate the number of matches to the keywords using this query:

```
SELECT ((FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%') +
        (FOODDES LIKE '%breast%') +
        (FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%')
        (FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%')
       ) as NumMatches, count(*), min(fooddes), max(fooddes)
FROM FOODDATA
GROUP BY (FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%') +
         (FOODDES LIKE '%breast%') +
         (FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%')
         (FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%')
ORDER BY NumMatches desc;
```

This query just counts the number of keywords that match and give the number of rows in `FOODDATA` that have 4 matches, 3 matches, and so on.

Comment: Thanks. Did not fully understand what you have done but accordingly to this http://i.imgur.com/rTXOX1S.png?1 they are combining 3 and 4 terms searches. Right?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```
 select 
 (FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%') + (FOODDES LIKE '%breast%') + (FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%') +  (FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%') As matches ,  
 FOODDES
 from 
 (
     SELECT FOODDES
     FROM FOODDATA
     WHERE FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%' or FOODDES LIKE '%breast%' or FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%' or FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%'
  ) table1
  where matches >=3
  order by matches desc
```

Comment: Thanks but got this: Error while executing query: no such column: .FOODDES

Comment: If FOODDES is your column name, then I think this should work. (See  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/1ac109/1/0 )

Comment: It was from the program I was using.

Answer (score -1):

Use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```
SELECT *
  FROM FOODDATA
 WHERE FOODDES LIKE '%chicken%' AND FOODDES LIKE '%breast%' AND FOODDES LIKE '%cooked%' AND FOODDES LIKE '%roasted%';
```

Also the character case may cause the difference. You are looking only for lowercase words and notice, that lots of their results start with a `Chicken`, with an uppercase. Add uppercase cases to your `AND` conditions and see results.

Also the Full Text Search extension to SQLite is a very good fit for this kind of queries (that is queries where you look for some words in longer texts). The `LIKE` is very slow (as for how fast databases are).

Comment: The question already says that `AND` gives only two results; and LIKE is not case sensitive.

Comment: @CL: It didn't when I answered the question. Also the fact that @Favolas didn't get correct answer with `AND` is that he didn't cover all necessary cases, not because `AND` is a wrong choice.